# How is code executed in a window service?

Tags: c#, service, window, execution

I was asked to develop a C# windows service. However I am used to create GUI with User Input.

Since windows services are automated, I would like to know how is the code executed.

I mean how can I control the flow?

Could someone clarify? I don't find a lot of information about window services...

Comment: I am just asking what would be done differently

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140002/where-can-i-find-a-detailed-view-of-the-lifecycle-of-a-windows-service-as-develo, which refers to a lot of resources

Answer (score 2):

Windows service starts exection from OnStart, usually a repeated execution starts from here could be a timer for instance. When service stops  OnStop method is called. This [**article**](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-a-simple-windows-service-in-csharp) could be a good starting point.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {
    base.OnStart(args);

    //TODO: place your start code here
  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
    base.OnStop();

    //TODO: clean up any variables and stop any threads
  }
```

Comment: Adil: Do you know if the Windows service will execute system calls? For me it doesnt work (starting the service with local system account).

Answer (score 2):

The code is started in the `OnStart()`

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Equivalent of Main()
    // Run threads here before timeout so OS knows it has started
}
```

Which you usually start a thread from to another function so that `OnStart()` can return and the service can start.

Same with `OnStop` and `OnShutdown` etc, where you would clean everything up.

Comment: You usually get 30 seconds for `OnStart`, et al to return - otherwise your process will be killed

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();

            serviceThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Delete));
            clientCleanupThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(removeExpirery));
            enableAutoSubscribeProduct = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Products));

            serviceThread.Start();
            clientCleanupThread.Start();


            enableAutoSubscribeProduct.Start();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log.Error("Error on thread start " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```