# Singleton vs GetSafeUninitializedObject

Tags: c#, reflection, singleton, system.reflection

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995408/what-is-the-net-object-life-cycle) answer by Marc Gravell on how to create an object without calling its constructor. Can someone confirm this will not circumvent even the complete and best implementation of singleton pattern(Reference implementations [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). And why? I guess more specifically I am not clear on the inner workings of GetSafeUninitializedObject() in the context of a Class's constructors (static, private etc)

Comment: Edited comment above:From the answers below, so there is no sure shot way for a Singleton author to ensure uniqueness. If I am a evil programmer with an intent to turn the world upside down, all I have to do is use GetSafeUninitializedObject on Singletons? Does that not mean all programs are vulnerable, no matter what? I understand that's true with any piece of code, other developers can always use your code in ways unintended, but specifically in this case, language can not provide a method to ensure singleton'ness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the singleton pattern you have a static variable on your type that will be initialized by the *type constructor*.

By calling `GetSafeUninitializedObject` you only avoid the *instance constructor* which will be called **after** the *type constructor*.

Example:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private static string _StaticMessage = "Type ctor;";

    private string _Message = "init; ";

    static Singleton()
    { }

    private Singleton()
    {
        _Message += "ctor; ";
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    public string Message { get { return _StaticMessage + _Message; } }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var singleton = Singleton.Instance;
        // writes "Type ctor;init; ctor;"
        Console.WriteLine(singleton.Message);

        var instance = (Singleton)System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices
        .GetSafeUninitializedObject(typeof(Singleton));

        // writes "Type ctor;"
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Message);
    }
}
```

#### Update to clarify difference between type initializer and static ctor asked from IllidanS4

This doesn't really belong to the answer above, but to the question within the comments: And a answer simply doesn't fit into a simple comment.

@IllidanS4: The type initializer is just a *shortcut* for writing an implicit static constructor. If you create a class that contains both initialization methods and decompile the resulting assembly you can see only one static constructor (.cctor) that will initialize all the variables. The both assignments will be merged where the type initializer will be called first and the statements within the static constructor last.

Take this sample class:

```
internal static class C
{
    public static readonly string ByTypeCtor;
    public static readonly string ByTypeInitializer = "From type init; ";
    public static string ByBoth = "From type init; ";

    static C()
    {
        ByTypeCtor = "From static ctor; ";
        ByBoth += "From static ctor";
    }
}
```

If you compile it and afterwards decompile it (e.g. by using [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) you'll get the following code back:

```
internal static class C
{
    public static readonly string ByTypeCtor;
    public static readonly string ByTypeInitializer;
    public static string ByBoth;
    static C()
    {
        C.ByTypeInitializer = "From type init; ";
        C.ByBoth = "From type init; ";
        C.ByTypeCtor = "From static ctor; ";
        C.ByBoth += "From static ctor";
    }
}
```

Due to this fact i normally never use to initialize a variable directly when it will be declared. Instead i always leave them uninitialized (like the `ByTypeCtor` variable) and make all initializations within the constructor. This simply avoids cluttering variable initialization to different positions within the class which improves maintainability.

Comment: Do you mean 'type initializer' or 'static constructor'?

Comment: @IllidanS4: The *static constructor* is the *type initializer*. If you know any difference between both, let me know.

Comment: "class C { static int f = 1; }" - class C has a type initializer (.cctor), but no static constructor. If you add "static C(){}", now it has both.

Comment: @IllidanS4: Take a look at [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2013/02/14/static-constructors-part-three) from Eric for a more in-depth analysis of static constructors and type initializers.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone has mentioned, it **can** circumvent and undermine your design pattern. 
But take a look at the recommended usage for `GetSafeUninitializedObject`

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getsafeuninitializedobject.aspx):

> GetSafeUninitializedObject should **only** be used for deserialization when the user intends to immediately populate all fields. It does not create an uninitialized string, since creating an empty instance of an immutable type serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default Singleton pattern is **definitely** better in *most* situations. The *expected* behaviour of your type, is that it's ctor has to be called.

Creating an object *without* calling ctor method on that type, is not something "normal", so I, personally, would **always** avoid using this solution till have **really** strong reasons to do so.

Side note: the singleton pattern is just a *pattern* and not framework behaviour. In my opinion, in this question, you mix 2 concepts that don't mix together.

The first case *is a way to create an object*, the second case, is *a way to architect code*.

General rule is: don't do "strange things" (`GetSafeUninitializedObject` is strange one), till you really need do so. Keep goinig on common shared across all developers patterns and keep things simple as much as it possible.

Answer (score 1):

The GetSafeUninitializedObject method works even on objects with private constructors, so it could potentially be used to circumvent the singleton pattern.